# Phpmailer, can't set needed 'from' email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

This code is work, email is sent

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->setFrom("name1@gmail.com", "Name");

$mail->addAddress($to); //Recipient name is optional

//Address to which recipient will reply
$mail->addReplyTo("name1@yahoo.com", "Reply");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;

if(!$mail->send())
    {
         echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . "\n";
    }
```

But for some reason, if I change From email to name2@yahoo.com

```
    $mail->setFrom("name2@yahoo.com", "Name");
```

emails does not sends anymore. Phpmailer does not report any error messages.

name2@yahoo.com is valid working email address related to this web server.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't change the code but the credentials, the second email obviously isn't working. Did you check if the credentials are correct, or if it's allowed to send over SMTP?

Comment: Thanks. I checked it once more and find what I can send letters with gmail domen, but not yahoo. Synchro is right, it's DMARC, also today I got letter about it.
About your question, on this host not necessary to set credentials for phpmailer, they set automatically in some way. I do not know details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.

Most service providers now have strict SPF and DMARC configurations (Yahoo especially, since they invented DMARC) that mean that you cannot send from addresses in their domains *except* through their own mail servers, or any others included in their SPF records.

Your code is sending through your own local server, which is not a Yahoo server, and thus won't work.

The solution is to send through Yahoo's own servers using authentication for your email account, something like:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'me@yahoo.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
```

Yahoo's DMARC config won't let you spoof the from address, so you can only use a from address that matches your username - this is probably the cause of the symptom you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks. You right, I thought about it, but couldn't find right information.
I checked it once more and find what I can send letters with gmail domen, but not yahoo.
Also today I got email with next text:

    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com said:
    550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to
    domain's 550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of
    yahoo.com domain if 550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit
    550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about
    the 550 5.7.1 DMARC initiative...